# How to add different gravity on spawning objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, rigid-bodies

Im working on a project that I want to create a power up effect whenever the button "Q" is pressed, I have the animation working and the character, I also have the spawning objects around my player that I want to spawn (See Figure below)
[image]
My question is how to add different gravity on each rock (spawning object).

Here is the script that I'm currently using.

```
/* Public Variables Declaration */
public Transform spawn_LocationForSmall;
public Transform spawn_LocationForMedium;
public Transform spawn_LocationForLarge;
public GameObject smallRock_Prefab;
public GameObject mediumRock_Prefab;
public GameObject largeRock_Prefab;

/* Private Variables Declaration */
private GameObject[] smallRocks_List;
private float posX, posY, posZ;

private bool smallCount = false;
private bool mediumCount = false;
private bool largeCount = false;

private bool small_CheckPos = false;
private bool medium_CheckPos = false;
private bool large_CheckPos = false;




void Start() {

    //smallRocks_List = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("smallRock");

    Create_Small_Rocks();

    Create_Medium_Rocks();

    Create_Large_Rocks();


}

 private void Create_Small_Rocks(){

    for(int i=0; i<=20; i++){

        small_CheckPos = false;
        posX = this.transform.position.x + Random.Range(-3.0f, 3.0f);
        posY = this.transform.position.y + Random.Range(-3.0f, 3.0f);
        posZ = this.transform.position.z + Random.Range(-3.0f, 3.0f);

        if(posX > 3f && posY > 3f){

            small_CheckPos = true;
        }

        if (small_CheckPos == true) {

            Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(posX, posY, posZ);

            GameObject createdObject = GameObject.Instantiate(smallRock_Prefab, 
                newPos, spawn_LocationForSmall.rotation) as GameObject;

            createdObject.transform.parent = spawn_LocationForSmall.transform;
        }

    }
    smallCount = true;
}
 /* the other two functions are similar to this */
```

Comment: Note: To check if tags are appropriate to use with your question, you can [read the description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gravity/info) of tags by clicking them and then clicking on "more info".

Comment: Why do you need different gravity for each rock?

Comment: Well realistically rocks dont have more gravity than others, they do have more mass though which you can change

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou yes, on the rigidbody change its mass, either in the prefab or through code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for Particle Systems :

1) https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.html

2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEA1wTMJAR0&t=536s

3) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xenW67bXTgM

- It allows you to upload cool effects or even prefabs as the clone objects (in this case rocks/asteroids). Its also able to control the spawning speed/ amount/ velosity/ (random)size/ physics(gravity)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know if you can change the gravity for each individual, but you can change these things:

**Mass:**
In the Rigidbody component, there is a "Mass" components at the top. As in the Unity Documentation says: "Higher mass objects push lower mass objects more when colliding. Think of a big truck, hitting a small car." However, it doesn't change how fast an object falls.

**Physics Material:**
In the Collider components, you should see something called "Material". You can create new physics materials and edit them randomly to make the friction between the rock and the surface higher or lower, and change the bounciness of rocks that way.

**Constant Force:**
If you want some objects to fall faster, you might want to use this component. I personally never used this before, but it looks great for your problem. You can add a constant force to an object with this component, so if you add some downwards force on your rocks it should help them get down faster.

Please let me know if any of these helped.

Comment: Helpful in understanding how physics works in Unity. Thanks @Qedized